How to have different layout in collection view depends on platform MAUI
<CollectionView>
<-- this should be for android-->
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout/>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
<-- this should be for ios-->
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout/>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>

I want to have that layout without using the "#" to separate the android or ios is there something like OnPlatform.

Yes you could use OnPlatform expression, Please check my answer.

You may  OnPlatform markup extension to customize different UI based on different platforms.
Let's say we have a CollecitonView defined in XAML named mycollection,
<CollectionView x:Name="mycollection" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    .....       
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>

Use OnPlatform markup extension
You may use OnPlatform expression in XAML,
<CollectionView x:Name="mycollection" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}" >
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ItemsLayout">
            <On Platform="iOS">
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" />
            </On>
            <On Platform="Android">
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="2"/>
            </On>
            <On Platform="WinUI">
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" />
            </On>
        </OnPlatform>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    ......

For more info, you may refer to Customize UI appearance based on the platform and device idiom.
